# Selecting Style Attributes in SVG Files with R

Tags: xml, r, svg

I want to use R to read in an SVG file, alter the SVG file based on data values and then export the SVG as a raster image such as a png.

Through some research I have ascertained that the package SVGMapping would have gotten me part way there however this package has been removed from the CRAN repository and I am therefore wary about using it for anything I may come to rely on.

Because SVG is XML, my plan is to use the XML package to alter attributes of my SVG file. I then want to call inkscape using the shell function to convert the SVG to a PNG.

I'm having trouble navigating the XML structure. As you can see in the SVG below, I have created three rectangles with different colours. I'd like to change the colours using R.

I can read in the SVG and navigate to the attributes using the following:

```
doc <- xmlTreeParse("c:\\Temp\\drawing.svg", getDTD = F)
doc$children$svg$children$g$children[1]$rect$attributes
```

I can then pull out all the style information using:

```
doc$children$svg$children$g$children[1]$rect$attributes["style"]
```

But then the result of this is just a character string containing values for fill, stroke, opacity etc.

```
"fill:#00ffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
```

Is there a way to select a single one of the style attributes, such as fill, so I can put a new colour code in?

I'm guessing I may end up using something regular expression based but thought I'd ask to see if there was an alternative (ie simpler!) way to navigate through the style attributes.

**SVG File:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<!-- Created with Inkscape (http://www.inkscape.org/) -->

<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   width="744.09448819"
   height="1052.3622047"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.2 r9819"
   sodipodi:docname="New document 1">
  <defs
     id="defs4" />
  <sodipodi:namedview
     id="base"
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1.0"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0.0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:zoom="0.53183594"
     inkscape:cx="375"
     inkscape:cy="520"
     inkscape:document-units="px"
     inkscape:current-layer="layer1"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:window-width="739"
     inkscape:window-height="558"
     inkscape:window-x="175"
     inkscape:window-y="175"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0" />
  <metadata
     id="metadata7">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <g
     inkscape:label="Layer 1"
     inkscape:groupmode="layer"
     id="layer1">
    <rect
       style="fill:#ff0000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="rect2985"
       width="180.50679"
       height="165.46455"
       x="30.084465"
       y="225.03938"
       rx="0"
       ry="0" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#00ff00;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="rect2985-1"
       width="180.50679"
       height="165.46455"
       x="312.12634"
       y="230.68022"
       rx="0"
       ry="0" />
    <rect
       style="fill:#00ffff;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"
       id="rect2985-7"
       width="180.50679"
       height="165.46455"
       x="118.45758"
       y="456.31369"
       rx="0"
       ry="0" />
  </g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Are you willing to modify the SVG file? You could replace the styles with attributes which would be easier to parse.

Answer (score 1):

As it stands you would need to process the `style` outside of the XML package. In this case you can split on
the `";"` and the `":"`

```
xData <- xmlParse("c:\\Temp\\drawing.svg")
out <- lapply(xData["//svg:rect"], xmlGetAttr, name = "style")
out <- sapply(out, strsplit, ";")
out <- lapply(out, strsplit, ":")
out <- lapply(out, function(x){
  sapply(x, function(y){`names<-`(y[2], y[1])})
}
)
out <- `names<-`(do.call(rbind.data.frame, out), names(out[[1]]))

out$fill <- "#000000"
out <- apply(out, 1, function(x) paste(names(out), x, sep = ':'))
out <- apply(out, 2, function(x) paste(x, collapse = ";"))

# remove old styles
lapply(xData["//svg:rect"], removeAttributes, .attrs = 'style')
# add new styles

mapply(addAttributes, node = xData["//svg:rect"], style = out)

> xData["//svg:rect"]
[[1]]
<rect id="rect2985" width="180.50679" height="165.46455" x="30.084465" y="225.03938" rx="0" ry="0" style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"/> 

[[2]]
<rect id="rect2985-1" width="180.50679" height="165.46455" x="312.12634" y="230.68022" rx="0" ry="0" style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"/> 

[[3]]
<rect id="rect2985-7" width="180.50679" height="165.46455" x="118.45758" y="456.31369" rx="0" ry="0" style="fill:#000000;fill-opacity:1;stroke:#000000;stroke-width:2;stroke-miterlimit:4;stroke-opacity:1;stroke-dasharray:none"/> 

attr(,"class")
[1] "XMLNodeSet"
```

Comment: This looks positive but I'm guessing I would still have issues incorporating any changes back into the original SVG

Comment: @Tumbledown you can change the attributes then add them back to the XML using `removeAttributes` and `addAttributes`

Comment: Thanks @jdharrison, I'm still having an issue getting the syntax quite right. I don't expect you to write my code for me but do you know of a decent example/tutorial which covers using removeAttributes and addAttributes? I've read the XML guidance but it's a little...functional. I'm beginning to think regex might be easier!

Comment: Oh and I experimented with modifying the SVG file as @robert-longson suggested. This does seem to simplify matters in terms of not having to break strings apart and the SVG is still interpreted fine.

Comment: I agree in this case I would just regex.